# PHP - are variables defined in a foreach loop local to that foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach, scope

Let's say I have this foreach:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $name = $item->name;
    $number = $item->number;
}
```

and I want to use them else where on the same page - say below the containing div like this:

```
<div>
    <!-- where the php foreach would go -->
</div>

<div>
 <?= $name ?>
</div>
```

would this break the page? or are the variables local to anywhere after the foreach loop?

Comment: It will not break the page, but it will probably have the value of the last name element of your loop

Comment: Loops don't have their own scope. `$name` and `$number` will be available anywhere in the scope the foreach is running in.

Comment: For more info, read this manual http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: If the `$items` array is ever empty then they wont get set, and would cause problems.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need a [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or a [`Generator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

Comment: Curious - why didn't you actually try this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did - it wasn't breaking but wasn't returning the value I was expecting

Comment: Then you should have put that information in your question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard didn't really seem necessary as I was asking more about variable scope

Comment: If you didn't get the value you were expecting and you thought it had something to do with variable scope they *all* go together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java and C++, variables declared inside blocks such as loops or if's, will also be recognized and accessible outside of the block. As written in PHP Manual.

Comment: ah cool thanks :) could you provide a link to the specific section?

Comment: You're welcome. Sure. Here is the  [link](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Thank you, will take a closer look into it all, thanks again :)